# What does this entry in an strace mean?

Tags: linux-kernel, strace

I already asked the question [on reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/AskProgramming/comments/buqx77/what_does_this_entry_in_an_strace_mean/), but it unfortunately received no responses.

I have the following shell output:

```
[OP@~]$ strace okular file.pdf
/* snipped */
write(13, "\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 8)        = 8
futex(0x5576a0f79370, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, NULLSettings::instance called after the first use - ignoring
Invalid Context= "Legacy" line for icon theme:  "/usr/share/icons/Adwaita/8x8/legacy/"
Invalid Context= "Legacy" line for icon theme:  "/usr/share/icons/Adwaita/16x16/legacy/"
Invalid Context= "UI" line for icon theme:  "/usr/share/icons/Adwaita/16x16/ui/"
Invalid Context= "Legacy" line for icon theme:  "/usr/share/icons/Adwaita/22x22/legacy/"
Invalid Context= "Legacy" line for icon theme:  "/usr/share/icons/Adwaita/24x24/legacy/"
Invalid Context= "UI" line for icon theme:  "/usr/share/icons/Adwaita/24x24/ui/"
Invalid Context= "Legacy" line for icon theme:  "/usr/share/icons/Adwaita/32x32/legacy/"
Invalid Context= "UI" line for icon theme:  "/usr/share/icons/Adwaita/32x32/ui/"
Invalid Context= "Legacy" line for icon theme:  "/usr/share/icons/Adwaita/48x48/legacy/"
Invalid Context= "UI" line for icon theme:  "/usr/share/icons/Adwaita/48x48/ui/"
Invalid Context= "Legacy" line for icon theme:  "/usr/share/icons/Adwaita/256x256/legacy/"
Invalid Context= "Legacy" line for icon theme:  "/usr/share/icons/Adwaita/512x512/legacy/"
Invalid Context= "UI" line for icon theme:  "/usr/share/icons/Adwaita/scalable/ui/"
org.kde.kcoreaddons: Expected JSON property "X-Purpose-PluginTypes" to be a single string. but it is a stringlist
discarding "Send SMS via KDE Connect..." "ShareUrl"
) = 0
futex(0x5576a0f79320, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 0
/* snipped */
```

How do I interpret the middle call to `futex`? Namely, there are a few things I don't understand:

- what is going on with the fourth argument? According to `futex(2)` in the manual, the prototype is

  ```
    int futex(int *uaddr, int futex_op, int val,
               const struct timespec *timeout,   /* or: uint32_t val2 */
               int *uaddr2, int val3);
  ```

  however, I don't see how this has type *timespec.
- In my version of the manual, the futex_op FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE is not described.

I'm running Arch Linux, and `strace` version 5.0.

EDIT: for context, what's happening is basically [this](https://github.com/numixproject/numix-core/issues/3277) problem. I was looking at the system trace hoping to gain some information. The reason I did this is because for some reason, the error message is displayed on my terminal, despite not being written to stdout or stderr. But in order to understand why, I think I need to understand this `futex` syscall.

Comment: Your `strace` output and command log is interleaved. That should probably be `futex(0x5576a0f79370, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, NULL) = 0`, with `Settings::instance...` etc., being from the command. Use `strace -o log` to get the strace output separately in a log.

Comment: Hmm.. unfortunately I recently upgraded my system and the problem went away, so I'll be unable to reproduce this. What is the command log you mentioned (where can I read about this)? I notice that this stuff isn't being written to stdout or stderr (as redirecting them doesn't do anything). However, it still shows up on my terminal.

Comment: The command log here is just the output of the command you ran, `okular`. It's a GUI program, those print a truckload of output. At least for me, `strace` writes to `stderr`, but that's probably where okular is dumping all that output too. If run `strace <some-command> 2>/dev/null`, I'll get no `strace` output.

Comment: @closevoters: This isn't off topic and isn't about a problem that cannot be repriduced. It's about understanding `strace` output.